# Setting up a Flask app in a Amazon EC2 instance, getting ImportError: No module named flask

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having issues trying to deploy my Flask app on an Amazon EC2 server.

I followed a tutorial [here](http://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/) and [here as well](http://alex.nisnevich.com/blog/2014/10/01/setting_up_flask_on_ec2.html).

When I go to run my server, after doing `sudo apachect1 restart` I get a 500 Internal Error when navigating to my ec2 site. Checking the log I get the following error.

```
[Tue Jun 20 19:10:48.429468 2017] [wsgi:error] ImportError: No module named flask, referer: http://ec2-<MY-EC2-URL>.amazonaws.com/
```

Though yet, through the PuTTY I am using to access the EC2 instance, I can see Python and flask are installed doing...

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__version__
'0.12.2'
```

Which I thought it/read it may be an issue of not finding my Python path. So I added in my configuration file for apache the `python-path=/usr/lib/python2.7`....

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    WSGIDaemonProcess leu threads=5 python-path=/usr/lib/python2.7
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/leu/app.wsgi

    <Directory leu>
        WSGIProcessGroup leu
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Yet still no luck. I've seen a lot with setting up Virtual Environments but I haven't done that. I originally created the project in PyCharm using Python 3.5, but then I went back through the project settings and created it with Python 2.7 and added all the corresponding imports. Still no luck when I did that.

Should I restart again with a virtualenv? Is there something I am missing with setting up Apache?

I was able to get the splash page for Apache saying I set it up correctly. [image]

**app.wsgi**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'var/www/html/leu')

from app import app as application
```

Any help?

**EDIT:** 
Also tried changing the path to Python in my Apache config file above to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` but still no luck

Comment: I think the first step is to make sure you can access the server locally. http://localhost:<port> on EC2. And then check the incoming port settings are open for that EC2 instance when trying to access it from your browser

Answer (score 1):

I know i am way too late....Hope this is useful to someone is struggling!

```
ServerName your EC2 instance
```

you have to mention your EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Install your modules with sudo -H .For example sudo -H pp install flask
if still persists then you have to change your configurations to use python 2.7 instead of python3